# Explain a step in proof.

Tags: probability

I have a problem. I hope everyone will explain for me. According to a article, author wrote: "we may and do assume that $|b_n| \ge 1$ for every $n \ge 1$." Why can author do this?? Thank everyone.

[image]

Comment: For $t>1$, it is clear that $\max\{|b_n|,1\}\leqslant t$ iff $|b_n|\leqslant t$.

Comment: Thanks. But If I do as the following: Since $|b_n|\to\infty$, exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $|b_n|\ge 1$ for all $n\ge n_0$. Hence, I have: $$  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} =  \sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1} \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} +  \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{|b_n|},  $$ in that  $\sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1} \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} $ is finite, I only need to proof $ \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{|b_n|}  $ to have $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} <\infty$. Is this right?